# Uploading multiple files to s3 using one put request

Tags: rest, httpwebrequest, streaming, amazon-s3, boto

I've got alot of small files that I'd like to put into s3. My goal is to minimize cost and use the fewest amount of put request's as possible. Is there anyway to stream multiple files onto s3 using only one put request? Currently the code I've implemented uses a put request per file and goes straight from the browser into s3. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check their API, there is batch() function to create a series of requests to be sent at once.

Comment: Can you provide me a link to that? I've been looking all over the documentation API and can't find anything. There is a batch put for simpledb but from what I can tell nothing for s3. Thanks for the help

Comment: See this, but I don't believe there is a way to do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15050914/1161429