# Pre-signed url for multiple files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have written an implementation for generating pre-signed URLS for a bucket on aws-s3. It works fine, for getting single files/objects.

How would I go about this for generating pre-signed URLS for entire directories? Lets put it this way, on my s3 bucket, there are multiple folders with their own small html5 applications. Each folder has their own set of html, css, js, as well as media files. I wouldn't be generating a pre-signed URL for single object, in this case.

If I give a pre-signed url for a single file, for example: an index.html for a folder, that file would also need to load css, js, and media files as well. Files we don't have a signed url for.

I'm just not too sure on how to go about implementing this.

Comment: Is this for a static website?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm aware that a pre-signed URL is only for single objects. I'm using static hosting as a workaround for now but there are directories that require authorization. Looking through the aws docs, I could create IAM users which would work nicely since I can group them, but it sounds like its for dev purposes, not necessarily for end-users.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, they would need to provide an API to allow you to upload multiple files first. This is a limitation of the API, not pre-signing.

See [Is it possible to perform a batch upload to amazon s3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15050146/241294).

Comment: I'm still unsure why this is the accepted answer?  I solved the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67830706/184752

Answer (score 46):

This is absolutely possible and has been for years.  You must use `conditions` when generating a presigned URL, specifically `starts-with`.  See the official [Amazon Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-ConditionMatching).

As an example, here is Python with Boto3 generating a presigned POST url:

```
    response = s3.generate_presigned_post(
        "BUCKET_NAME",
        "uploads/${filename}",
        Fields=None,
        Conditions=[["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"]],
        ExpiresIn=(10 * 60),
    )
```

Comment: Be cautious with your starts with key but this works!

Comment: May I need to specify  **${filename}** on key param of that method? but I want to add multiple different files with same presined post url. I want to use `"uploads/"` instead of `"uploads/${filename}"`

Comment: @DavidMerritt Can you elaborate on why one needs to be cautious?

Comment: This is not dynamic. You need to run `generate_presigned_post` for each `${filename}` that you want to upload.

Comment: How do you use `response` to open an HTML application like OP requested? Mine looks like `{'url': 'https://folder.s3.amazonaws.com/', 'fields': {'key': 'user1/reports1/index.html', 'AWSAccessKeyId': '***', 'policy': '***', 'signature': '***'}}`

Comment: Isn't the Condition just additional restriction on this request, but in principle key have to match: `uploads/${filename}` anyway?

Comment: This solution is specific to the AWS library for Python. Any solutions for other languages?

Comment: I was able to achieve this with Node.js `createPresignedPost` function available in package `@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post`. You don't need to set the filename when creating the presigned url for each file, ${filename} works

Answer (score 12):

No. A pre-signed URL is valid for only one object.

Answer (score 2):

First things first:
AWS S3 is a key value store, each object `aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/index.html` is just one name.  There is no concept of "folders" ( even though you might have a false impression that they exists from the UI ).

In order to create a single presigned url for multiple "files" you have to do some preprocessing.  Pull all necessary files locally, zip them and put zip archive on S3, then generate presigned URL of zip archive.

Comment: Technically S3 is a KV store with no folders, but practically speaking "folders" do exist there. You can already set bucket policies [based on key path](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/6215d9e80021c1f8de12#getputdelete-access-to-specific-path-within-a-bucket) to essentially set policies on folders. But presigned URLs do not (currently) support partial key paths. And even if they did, it wouldn't help the OP because the HTML application is still linking to resources (css, js at same key prefix) without the presigned URL.

Answer (score 0):

This would generate a pre-signed URL for the existing object on the S3. In your case you could list down all the objects (using the keyName) and call the above method recursively.

```
public String generatePreSignedUrl(String bucketName, String keyName){

    Date expiration = new Date();
    long mSec = 60000l;     //Time in millis
    expiration.setTime(mSec);

    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, keyName);
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

    URL url = s3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
    return url.toString();
}
```

PS: The AWS SDK provides API to list down the objects under the bucket & you could pick the required objects.

Comment: How would you use this to open an HTML application like OP requested?

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else looking at this issue in 2021 - the easiest way that I found to download an entire "folder" of files from an S3 bucket was to change how I uploaded a "folder". Instead of recursively uploading, I swapped to zip the objects into a single zip archive, then upload the zip archive. It doesn't directly answer the question but is a quick work-around. Here is the example python code that I used to get around this problem:

`from shutil import make_archive`

`from boto3 import client`

`make_archive(name_of_zipped_folder, 'zip', path_to_outdir)`

Then upload this zipped folder to s3

`aws s3 cp name_of_zipped_folder s3://bucket_name/name_of_zipped_folder`

Then use boto3 code to generate presigned urls for that zipped folder

`client('s3', 'us-east-1').generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,'Key': name_of_zipped_folder}, ExpiresIn=120)`

Comment: I like your thinking "outside the box", but it's a very static solution that isn't very scalable. For example, if your ZIP file is 10 GB, and you want to change one line of code in some css file, then you have to reupload the entire zip file. Good workaround for small files, though