# Does AWS make external API calls to generate signed S3 links?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to generate pre-signed S3 links for existing objects in the bucket in bulk.

To achieve this, I can run `S3.getSignedUrl()` in a loop but I am not sure if this function runs locally or makes an API call to AWS.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951788/bulk-generate-pre-signed-urls-boto3/53952138#53952138) says it is done locally, but this is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

How can I verify that it doesn't make an external API call?

I am using `aws-sdk-js` package.

I went through the actual implementation of the [getSignedUrl](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/a865a2b3153c0e18e4ba50e510cc363f06212b16/lib/services/s3.js#L910) from the SDK:

```
function getSignedUrl(operation, params, callback) {
    params = AWS.util.copy(params || {});
    var expires = params.Expires || 900;

    if (typeof expires !== 'number') {
      throw AWS.util.error(new Error(),
        { code: 'InvalidParameterException', message: 'The expiration must be a number, received ' + typeof expires });
    }

    delete params.Expires; // we can't validate this
    var request = this.makeRequest(operation, params);

    if (callback) {
      AWS.util.defer(function() {
        request.presign(expires, callback);
      });
    } else {
      return request.presign(expires, callback);
    }
  }
```

Here, a request is being created. Does it make an external API call?

Comment: It *is* running locally. It just produces a cryptographic signature based on your API credentials. Otherwise it would be called something-something-token, which produces a token on the AWS server.

Comment: @deceze How can check if it runs locally? I mean the function doesn't call external api? Is there any way to verify? Doesn't it validate s3 credentials before generating the url?

Comment: Worst case: benchmark it and compare how much time it takes compared to a request that you know makes a network request. Perhaps disconnect your internet connection and see if it still works…

Comment: @deceze That's an option. Can we verify checking code or the implementation of the method? Or is there any documentation that supports your statement?