# AWS S3 generate_presigned_url vs generate_presigned_post for uploading files

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

I was working on uploading and downloading a file to S3 bucket using pre-signed URLs.I came across these two methods `generate_presigned_url('put_object')` and `generate_presigned_post`.

**What is the difference between these two methods?**

```
# upload a file to a bucket with generate_presigned_url with put object
s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object', Params= {'Bucket': "BUCKET_NAME",
                                                        "Key":"OBJECT_KEY"},
                                                         ExpiresIn=3600)
  

# upload a file to a bucket using presigned post
s3_client.generate_presigned_post(Bucket="BUCKET_NAME", Key="OBJECT_PATH",
                                  ExpiresIn=3600)
```

Could someone please explain the difference between both?

If we have `generate_presigned_post` why was there a `generate_presigned_url` method with `put_object` for uploading in the first place.

Note :  I know that `generate_presigned_post` is the recommended method for file uploads and I have used the same. However, there is no clear documentation on the difference between these methods.

Comment: Here is the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html) for POST. `generate_presigned_url` is a general method that is not limited to generating a PUT url. You can also use it to grant someone permission temporarily to GetObject in a private bucket for example.

Comment: Thanks.. I do understand that generate_presigned_url is generic and applicable for both upload and download. But i am just curious if there is a specific difference between them. Why is post required when we already have a method

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is an extended version of @jellycsc's comment. I had posted the same query to aws support as well. I got the below answer from them.

More detailed explanation is given [here](https://advancedweb.hu/differences-between-put-and-post-s3-signed-urls/)

Posting here as it could be useful for someone.

**What is the difference between these two methods?**

`generate_presigned_post()` is more powerful because of the POST [Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) feature. The POST Policy is simply conditions you set when creating the presigned POST. Using it, you can allow certain MIME types and file extensions, allow multiple files to be uploaded with a given prefix, restrict the file size, and more, which is not possible in `generate_presigned_url()`

Please note that both the methods can be used to fulfill the same goal, i.e provide controlled way for users to upload files directly to S3 buckets. The process is also the same for both as the backend needs to sign the request after validating that the user is authorized then the browser sends the file directly to S3.

**Differences:**

**URLStructure:**

PUT URLs encode everything in the URL itself as there is nothing else communicated back to the client. This means fewer variables can be customized.

POST URLs use multiple fields for different kinds of information. The signing algorithm returns a list of fields along with the URL itself and the client must send those to S3 as well while accessing the presigned URL.

While PUT URLs provide a destination to upload files without any other required parts, POST URLs are made for forms that can send multiple fields. However, their usage is not limited to forms.

**Content Type**

For PUT URLs the signing must be done for a specific content type. That means you either hardcode a content type on the backend, for example, application/xml if you want to allow users to upload XML documents, or the client must send the desired content type as part of the signing request.

For POST URLs the policy supports a prefix constraint as well as an exact match.

**Content-Length:**

In case of PUT URLs, you have no control over the size of the uploaded file.

For POST URLs you can set an allowed range in the policy.

**Sample presigned post in python:**

```
response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(Bucket="BUCKET_NAME",
                                                     Key="S3KEY",
                                                     Fields={"Content-Type": "image/jpg"},
                                                     Conditions=["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
                                                     ExpiresIn=3600)
```

Comment: I don't think that this is correct _"allow multiple files to be uploaded with a given prefix"_. As far as I know, a post URL is invalidated once it has been used

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. You are right. The presigned URLs are valid only for a single upload. However, I happened to read another SO answer that it's possible with conditions set. I haven't tried it myself though. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344194/pre-signed-url-for-multiple-files#:~:text=Yes%20it%20is.,is%20only%20for%20single%20objects. Have you ever tried POST with conditions?

Comment: Actually, just tested it and it looks like presigned PUT and POST URLs can be reused after first successful upload. The presigned PUT will overwrite existing objects in S3, when invoked again. Same for the POST URLs, unless you set the key as `${filename}` then you can upload multiple files with the same URL. So means, you were correct from the start

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I believe the presigned URLs get invalidated after their expiry if conditions are set.

Comment: Don't forget about the `$` prefix in `$Content-Type` parameter if used in conditions!!!