# Uploading to Amazon S3 with Angular 2 using presigned URLs

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

In my Angular/ Django Rest Framework I want to upload pictures to an Amazon S3 Bucket.

I need to use `Presigned URLs` since it's faster and more secure than uploading directly client side.

So far I managed to create and retreive the Presigned URL but I am struggling using it for uploading my picture.

This is the view I am using in Django to create the Presigned Url:

```
class GenerateAwsSignature(View):

    def get(self, request, object_name):
        bucket_name = "moviepictures"
        presigned_url = create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name)        
        return JsonResponse({"presigned_url": presigned_url})


def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name,
                         fields=None, conditions=None, expiration=3600):

    load_dotenv()
    AWS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY_ID,
                             aws_secret_access_key=AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
    response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(bucket_name,
                                                 object_name,
                                                 Fields=fields,
                                                 Conditions=conditions,
                                                 ExpiresIn=expiration)
    return response
```

My component:

```
onUpload() {
    const name = this.selectedFile.name
    this.s3Upload.getPresignedUrl(name)
      .subscribe(r => {
        console.log(r)
        this.s3Upload.uploadFile(r, this.selectedFile)
          .subscribe(r => console.log("uploaded :)"))
      })
  }
```

This is the log of my Presigned URL whenever I want to upload a picture called "Batman" into a bucket called "moviepictures":

```
presigned_url:
fields:
AWSAccessKeyId: "AKIAYHDIXNIEPY2PQJ6V"
key: "batman"
policy: "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMjEtMDctMDhUMTc6MTY6MTdaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJidWNrZXQiOiAibW92aWVwaWN0dXJlcyJ9LCB7ImtleSI6ICJiYXRtYW4ifV19"
signature: "pCjcs4TE1Qyj62v2KveCoMM1tXo="
__proto__: Object
url: "https://moviepictures.s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

And the service for uploading to my Bucket:

```
uploadFile(r: any, selectedFile: any) {
    return this.http.put(r['url'], r['fields'], selectedFile)
  }
```

Whenever I want to upload I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

So what is the correct way to use the fields I have to upload my picture in my Bucket?

Answer (score 1):

After trying with no luck to fix my code I've decided to switch from `s3_client.generate_presigned_post()` to  `s3_client.generate_presigned_url()`. For more information about their difference, you can check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198959/aws-s3-generate-presigned-url-vs-generate-presigned-post-for-uploading-files).
Basically instead of getting different fields you get only one url with everything you need for uploading in it.
Just don't forget to add a `"signature_version"` and most important to overwrite the header "content-type" with the file you want to upload MIME type.
In my case I add `{'content-type': 'imge/jpeg'}` to my header because by default it would be `'application/xml'` and I would get the `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error.

This method is working 100% in Postman, so I just have to implement it in my app.

```
 my_config = Config(
        region_name='eu-west-3',
        signature_version='s3v4',
        retries = {
            'max_attempts': 10,
            'mode': 'standard'
        }
    )


def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=3600):

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                            aws_access_key_id="#########",
                            aws_secret_access_key="##########",
                            config=my_config)
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name ,
                                                            'Key': object_name,
                                                            "ContentType": "image/jpeg" },
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    return response

url = create_presigned_url("bemytest", "batman.jpg")
```