# Retrieve multiple objects with presigned URL from S3 python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get multiple objects from an S3 bucket using python with aws cli installed and configure. I can currently get a single file using this code.

```
import boto3


url = boto3.client('s3').generate_presigned_url(
ClientMethod='get_object', 
Params={'Bucket': 'test-bucket', 'Key':'00001.png'},
ExpiresIn=3600)

print(url)
```

However I need to generate the same for 100 other image files, how can I possibly do this?

Comment: I think this could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344194/pre-signed-url-for-multiple-files/67830706#67830706

Answer (score 0):

Run the code 100 times -- seriously!

You should separate out the client generation, such as:

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(...)
```

It's a very quick command and doesn't require a call to AWS so you can repeat or loop-through the last line many times.

Each object will require a separate pre-signed URL because permission is being generated for just one object at a time.