# is this possible to create a folder in s3 and generate pre signed post urls for folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

there is a specific use case for which I am trying to solve . Issue is by using boto3 I want to create a folder first and generate presigned post urls for that specific folder . but for now I found that I can't create a new folder I have to upload some file on that directory first and 2nd thing  can't generate presigned post url for whole folder I have to do this for 1 by 1 file ? Is my conclusion right or I am going wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Correct.  S3 doesn't really have folders, it has some ways to group objects with a common separator.  Presigned URLs are for an object only, never for a collection of objects.

Comment: That not entirely true, you may be able to create presigned url for multiple files. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67830706/7661119

Comment: Ahh, good point!