# Using the Condition Starts-With in S3 .NET Client

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, startswith

I'm working with the S3 .net client and I'm perfectly able to get a presigned url (I followed [this tutorial](https://andyp.dev/posts/generate-aws-s3-presigned-keys-in-c-for-jquery-frontend) online). I would like to let the user to store their files in a specific path only (for example into the 'testtest/' folder).

As explained also here in [another StackFlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344194/pre-signed-url-for-multiple-files#answer-67830706), is possible to use:

```
Conditions=[["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"]]
```

I'm using the .net S3 client and actually seems that there is no way to set this condition.
Do you have an idea how to set "starts-with" option?

I tried to use the "parameters" as show in the following lines without success.

```
        < !--language - all: cs-- >
        GetPreSignedUrlRequest request1 = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
        {
            BucketName = _BucketName,
            Key = key,
            Expires = expiryTime,
            Verb = HttpVerb.PUT
        };
        request1.Parameters.Add("Conditions", "[\"starts-with\", \"testtest/\"]"); // <== THIS LINE
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you had the right idea, but your condition was not valid. Conditions is actually an array of conditions, and `starts-with` needs to know what to look at, so something like this should work:

```
Parameters = { ["Conditions"] = "[[\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"testtest/\"]]" }
```

Whether or not this actually helps is somewhat debatable. It seems the best practice is to get a signed URL for each file (key) before uploading against it.